# unset form error for specific field

Tags: forms, 8

I have a a kind of conditional field for a sign up form where the user can optionally sign up with a mobile number or an email address.

I'm trying out a custom form validate eg.

```
  function signup_validate($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $mobile = $form_state->getValue('field_mobile');
    $email = $form_state->getValue('field_email_address');

    if ($email[0]['value'] != '' || $mobile[0]['value'] != '') {
      $form_state->clearErrors();
    }
  }
```

Now `clearErrors();`  obviously clears all errors for the form even if other fields are invalid, I want to know how to clear the error only for `field_mobile` or `field_email_address`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of removing the error, you should make sure that only the needed validation errors are set in the first place.

For example, you could use '#states' in your form elements to set 'required' depending on the user input of the other field.

Comment: States affect only client side validation, not server side.  "Since states are driven by JavaScript only, it is important to understand that all states are applied on presentation only" > https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/form-api/conditional-form-fields#statesproperty

Answer (score 27):

While I agree with the accepted answer, one way to accomplish your goal is to:

1. Assign the form errors to a variable, such as `$form_errors`
2. Clear all form errors from `$form_state`
3. Remove the particular form error from `$form_errors`
4. Loop through the remaining `$form_errors`, re-setting them to `$form_state`.

So to clear the `field_mobile` error you would use the following code:

```
// Temporarily store all form errors.
$form_errors = $form_state->getErrors();

// Clear the form errors.
$form_state->clearErrors();

// Remove the field_mobile form error.
unset($form_errors['field_mobile']);

// Now loop through and re-apply the remaining form error messages.
foreach ($form_errors as $name => $error_message) {
  $form_state->setErrorByName($name, $error_message);
}
```

Comment: For me this requirement it's needed on credit card fields required with no name attribute and for security reasons not received on my server, only a token from my payment provider.

Comment: Ended up needing to use for a plugin configuration form in `validateConfigurationForm()` as I couldn't get #states to function as expected.

Comment: It's working for me

Comment: Good answer. Should be the accepted answer.